# Returning the differences between lists of lists

Tags: python, comparison, spyder

I have been having difficulty trying to create a method to return the differences between lists of lists. This is basically what I am looking for:

```
s1r1=[[1,2,3,4,5,6],[2,4,6,8]]
uniq=[1,3,5,8]
```

I have been trying to use this method

```
list(set(s1r1[0])-set(s1r1[1]))
```

but it has only been returning the number '8'. I then tried using this format

```
list(set(a).symmetric_difference(set(b))
```

and it is now saying that I have a syntax error on the last line of my script, even if there is nothing present. Does anyone have any insight?

Comment: So what exactly is your expected output? Per your example, you are representing a list of numbers as a single string, which is generally not a good idea...

Comment: shouldn't s1r1 be `s1r1 = [[1,2,3,4,5,6], [2,4,6,8]]`? Right now you have a a list of 2 strings :/

Comment: @Srini that is correct, I will fix that

Answer (score 1):

Using ^ operator for symmetric_difference

```
a=set([1,2,3,4,5,6])
b=set([2,4,6,8])
a^b
```

Output

{1, 3, 5, 8}

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s1r1 = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[2,4,6,8]]
>>> list(set(s1r1[0]).symmetric_difference(s1r1[1]))
['1', '5', '8', '3']
```

Alternatively you the `^` operator for symmetric difference.

```
>>> list (set(s1r1[0]) ^ set(s1r1[1]))
[1, 3, 5, 8]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and why it solves the problem will make this answer more useful (and more likely to attract up-votes!)

Answer (score 0):

This will work for any number of lists:

```
s1r1=[[1,2,3,4,5,6],[2,4,6,8]]

uniq = [[j for j in k if not all(j in i for i in s1r1)] for k in s1r1]
```

Yields:

```
[[1, 3, 5], [8]]
```

And to return it as a single list:

```
print([j for i in uniq for j in i])
```

Yields:

```
[1, 3, 5, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to *cast* to `list` to do a symmetric difference
(disregard the `In:` `Out:` they're from my iPython terminal)

```
In [16]: s1r1 = [[1,2,3,4,5,6], [2,4,6,8]]

In [19]: a = set(s1r1[0])

In [20]: b = set(s1r1[1])

In [21]: ans = a.union(b) - a.intersection(b)

In [22]: print ans
set([8, 1, 3, 5])

In [23]: ans = a.symmetric_difference(b)

In [24]: print ans
set([1, 3, 5, 8])
```

Symmetric difference is just the opposite of an intersection

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = set(s1r1[0])
>>> b = set(s1r1[1])
>>> uniq = a.union(b) - a.intersection(b)
>>> uniq    
{8, 1, 3, 5}
```